# react native navigation: android app crashes (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme)

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, branch.io, react-native-navigation

We have recently started to use react-native-navigation ( instead of react-navigation ).
The iOS version works perfectly fine, but we have trouble configuring the android app. I have modified the MainActivity and MainApplication.java based on the Installation Manual and other examples, But Still i can't get it work.

MainActivity:

```java
package com.client;
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

}
```

MainApplication.java:

```java
package com.client;

import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.amazonaws.RNAWSCognitoPackage;
import com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage;
import org.reactnative.camera.RNCameraPackage;
import com.inprogress.reactnativeyoutube.ReactNativeYouTube;
import io.sentry.RNSentryPackage;
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;
import com.transistorsoft.rnbackgroundgeolocation.RNBackgroundGeolocation;
import com.react.rnspinkit.RNSpinkitPackage;
import com.avishayil.rnrestart.ReactNativeRestartPackage;
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n.RNI18nPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import io.branch.referral.Branch;
import com.vydia.RNUploader.UploaderReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.ActivityCallbacks;
import io.branch.rnbranch.*;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private Activity activityInstance;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setActivityCallbacks(new ActivityCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
          activityInstance = activity;
          RNBranchModule.initSession(activity.getIntent().getData(), activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
          activityInstance.setIntent(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    });
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

  @Override
   public boolean isDebug() {
       return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
   }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    new VectorIconsPackage(),
    new RNAWSCognitoPackage(),
    new OrientationPackage(),
    new RNCameraPackage(),
    new ReactNativeYouTube(),
    new RNSentryPackage(MainApplication.this),
    new RNFSPackage(),
    new RNSpinkitPackage(),
    new ReactNativeRestartPackage(),
    new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage(),
    new ImagePickerPackage(),
    new RNI18nPackage(),
    new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
    new RNDeviceInfo(),
    new RNBranchPackage(),
    new UploaderReactPackage(),
    new RNBackgroundGeolocation(),
    new MapsPackage()
    );
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.client">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/iamsmart">
      <!-- google maps api key -->
      <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="xxxxx"/>
      <meta-data
      android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.license"
      android:value="xxxxx"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://link.xxxx.com/” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="link.xxxx.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/" />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "xxxx://users” -->
            <data android:scheme="xxxx"
                android:host="users" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="invite.xxxx.com" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="invite.xxxx.com" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <!-- Branch init -->
      <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="xxxxx" />
      <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="kxxxx" />
      <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />

      <!-- Branch install referrer tracking (optional) -->
      <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```js
03-20 12:57:55.314 20308 20308 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.xxxxx.android.client, PID: 20308
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.android.client/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:158)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:151)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.views.TopBar.<init>(TopBar.java:43)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.Screen.createTopBar(Screen.java:164)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.Screen.createAndAddTopBar(Screen.java:159)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.Screen.createViews(Screen.java:122)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:62)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.SingleScreen.<init>(SingleScreen.java:16)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.ScreenFactory.create(ScreenFactory.java:23)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.screens.ScreenStack.pushInitialScreen(ScreenStack.java:96)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.layouts.SingleScreenLayout.pushInitialScreen(SingleScreenLayout.java:92)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.layouts.SingleScreenLayout.createStack(SingleScreenLayout.java:87)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.layouts.SingleScreenLayout.createLayout(SingleScreenLayout.java:64)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.layouts.SingleScreenLayout.<init>(SingleScreenLayout.java:56)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.layouts.LayoutFactory.createSingleScreenLayout(LayoutFactory.java:20)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.layouts.LayoutFactory.create(LayoutFactory.java:15)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity.createLayout(NavigationActivity.java:100)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity.onCreate(NavigationActivity.java:81)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
03-20 12:57:55.318 20308 20308 E AndroidRuntime:  ... 9 more
03-20 12:57:55.323 20308 20308 D io.sentry.android.event.helper.AndroidEventBuilderHelper: Proguard UUIDs file not found.
03-20 12:57:55.380 20308 20354 I react-native-sentry: captureEvent '{ NativeMap: {"level":"log","category":"console","message":"Running application \"Menu\" with appParams: {\"initialProps\":{\"screenInstanceID\":\"screenInstanceID4\",\"navigatorID\":\"navigatorID3_nav\",\"navigatorEventID\":\"screenInstanceID4_events\"},\"rootTag\":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF","timestamp":1521550675.308} }'
03-20 12:57:55.453  1582  2757 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.xxxxx.android.client/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, this is not a Branch-related issue.

`AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.android.client/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.`

There are some other resources on StackOverflow that might solve your issue:

- [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)